# Treat GraphData output as a graph object input for other functions

Tags: graphs-and-networks, curated-data

When I run `GraphData` it gives me a list of graphs names, but unfortunately this list is unstructured: some graphs are given just by names (`"ClawGraph"`, `"DiamondGraph"`, etc.), some as a combination of names and numbers (`{"LadderRung",2}`, `{"Empty",4}`) and some as just a couple of numbers (`{4,2}`).

I want to give all these graphs as an input in some cycle (to be more precise, to sum over all these graphs). How should I deal with all possible different name formats?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation page of `GraphData`, and did you check the examples? Did you look under "Details"?  (You need to expand those sections.)  I think it's explained quite clearly there.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply apply `GraphData` again to the results:

```
GraphData /@ GraphData[3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]